# Почему нельзя использовать модель GPT-3.5

Tags: python, api, requests, python-openai

я вот старался отправить запрос на модель GPT-3.5, но я получаю текст ошибки о том что модель не найдена

а мне нужно использовать бесплатную модель GPT-3.5, так как я хочу написать библиотеку OpenAi-remastered

Мой код:

```py
import requests

def test_requests():
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer ВАШ_КЛЮЧ_API"
    }

    payload = {
        "model": "gpt-3.5",
        "messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "Say this is a test!"}],
        "temperature": 0.7
    }

    response = requests.post("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", headers=headers, json=payload)

    return response.json()

print(test_requests())
```

Comment: Если вы почитали бы [документацию](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3-5), то поняли бы, что не существует модели `gpt-3.5`, есть `gpt-3.5-turbo`, `gpt-3.5-turbo-16k` и так далее. Внимательней будьте, изучайте информацию перед тем, как просить помощь у людей.